# Use pandas to conditionally format substrings in Excel

Tags: excel, pandas, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel table like so:

```
+------------+-----------------------+
|  String1   |        String2        |
+------------+-----------------------+
| Example 1  | This is example 1     |
| Example 2  | The second Example, 2 |
+------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm trying to compare the two strings, and format them conditionally. Ideally, I'd be able to create a third column, with the string difference in bold (or whatever formatting I want, applied) like so:

+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| String1 |          String2         |   Formatted String  |
+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Example 1  | This is Example 1   | **This is** Example 1   |
| Example 2  | The second Example, 2 | **The second** Example, 2 |
+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+

I know that using XlsxWriter I can apply conditional formatting to a df as I'm writing to excel, but it seems I can only do that to an *entire* cell. Is there any way to apply my formatting to some contents of each cell?

Alternatively, could I insert HTML tags into my df to produce say, "<b>This is</b> Example 1" and then render those tags in excel?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering this problem: XlsxWriter can output rich strings. You have to define all your formats explicitly, but it works.